# What am I doing wrong when building this twisted web scraper?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twisted

Can you please show me the error in my twisted ways?  I have been struggling to build a fast web scraper using twisted for quite some time.  Building a traditional threaded **scraper** using Queue was a piece of cake and, has so far, been oodles faster.  Still, I want to compare twisted!  The goal of the webscraper is to recursively find image () links from a gallery, and connect to those image links to scrape images () and/or gather more image links to parse later. The code is shown below.  Most of the functions pass a dictionary so I could packet all the information from each link more conceptually.  I try to thread what would otherwise be blocking code (parsePage function) and use "asynchronous code" (or so I believe) for retrieving html pages, header info, and images.

My main issue so far has been getting a ton of "User timeout caused connection failure" traced back from either my getLinkHTML or getImgHeader errback.  I have tried throttling the number of connections i make using semaphores and have even caused some of my code to sleep to no avail, thinking I was inundating the connections.  I also thought the issue might arise from reactor.connectTCP since the timeout errors generate after approximately ~30 seconds of running the **scraper** , and connectTCP has a 30 second timeout.  However, I moded the connectTCP code from the twisted module to 60s, and the timeout errors still occured circa 30 seconds after running.  Off course, **scraping** the same sites with my traditional threaded **scraper** works fine and much much much faster.

So what am I doing wrong?  Also, please feel free to critique me on the code in general as  I am self-taught and I have some random questions throughout the code as well.  Any advice is well appreciated!

```
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import client
from lxml import html
from StringIO import StringIO
from os import path
import re

start_url = "http://www.thesupermodelsgallery.com/"
directory = "/home/z0e/Pictures/Pix/Twisted"
min_img_size = 100000

#maximum <a> links to get from main gallery
max_gallery_links = 500

#maximum <a> links to get from subsequent gallery/pages
max_picture_links = 35

def parsePage(info):
         
    def linkFilter(link):
    #filter unwanted <a> links
    if link is not None:
        trade_match = re.search(r'&trade=', link)
        href_split = link.split('=')
        for i in range(len(href_split)):
            if 'www' in href_split[i] and i > 0:
                link = href_split[i]
        end_pattern = r'\.(com|com/|net|net/|pro|pro/)$'
        end_match = re.search(end_pattern, link)
        p_pattern = r'(.*)&p'
        p_match = re.search(p_pattern, link)
        if end_match or trade_match:
            return None
        elif p_match:
            link = p_match.group(1)
            return link
        else:
            return link
    else:
        return None
        
    # better to handle a link with 'None' value through TypeError
    # exception or through if else statements?  Compare linkFilter
    # vs. imgFilter functions
        
    def imgFilter(link):
    #filter <img> links to retain only .jpg
    try:
        jpg_match = re.search(r'.jpg', link)
        if jpg_match is not None:
            return link
        else:
            return None
    except TypeError:
        return None
        
    link_num = 0
    gallery_flag = None
    info['level'] += 1
    if info['page'] is '':
    return None
    # use lxml to parse and get document root
    tree = html.parse(StringIO(info['page']))
    root = tree.getroot()
    root.make_links_absolute(info['url'])
    # info['level'] = 1 corresponds to first recursive layer (i.e. main gallery page)
    # info['level'] > 1 will be all other <a> links from main gallery page
    if info['level'] == 1:
    link_cap = max_gallery_links
    gallery_flag = True
    else:
    link_cap = max_picture_links
    gallery_flag = False
    if info['level'] > 4:
    return None
    else:
    
    # get <img> links if page is not main gallery ('gallery_flag = False')
    # put <img> links back into main event loop to extract header information
    # to judge pictures by picture size (i.e. content-length)
    if not gallery_flag:
        for elem in root.iter('img'):
            # create copy of info so that dictionary no longer points to 
            # previous dictionary, but new dictionary for each link
            info = info.copy()
            info['url'] = imgFilter(elem.get('src'))
            if info['url'] is not None:
                reactor.callFromThread(getImgHeader, info) 
                
    # get <a> link and put work back into main event loop (i.e. w/ 
    # reactor.callFromThread...) to getPage and then parse, continuing the
    # cycle of linking        
    for elem in root.iter('a'):
        if link_num > link_cap:
            break
        else:
            img = elem.find('img')
            if img is not None:
                link_num += 1
                info = info.copy()
                info['url'] = linkFilter(elem.get('href'))
                if info['url'] is not None:
                    reactor.callFromThread(getLinkHTML, info)
                    
def getLinkHTML(info):
    # get html from <a> link and then send page to be parsed in a thread
    d = client.getPage(info['url'])
    d.addCallback(parseThread, info)
    d.addErrback(failure, "getLink Failure: " + info['url'])
    
def parseThread(page, info):
    print 'parsethread:', info['url']
    info['page'] = page
    reactor.callInThread(parsePage, info)

def getImgHeader(info):
    # get <img> header information to filter images by image size
    agent = client.Agent(reactor)
    d = agent.request('HEAD', info['url'], None, None)
    d.addCallback(getImg, info)
    d.addErrback(failure, "getImgHeader Failure: " + info['url'])

def getImg(img_header, info):
    # download image only if image is above a certain threshold size
    img_size = img_header.headers.getRawHeaders('Content-Length')  
    if int(img_size[0]) > min_img_size and img_size is not None:
    img_name = ''.join(map(urlToName, info['url']))
    client.downloadPage(info['url'], path.join(directory, img_name))
    else:
    img_header, link = None, None #Does this help garbage collecting?
    
def urlToName(char):
    #convert all unwanted characters to '-' from url and use as file name
    if char in '/\?|<>"':
    return '-'
    else:
    return char
    
def failure(error, url):
    print error
    print url

def main():
    info = dict()
    info['url'] = start_url
    info['level'] = 0
    
    reactor.callWhenRunning(getLinkHTML, info)    
    reactor.suggestThreadPoolSize(2)
    reactor.run()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

First, consider not writing this code at all.  Take a look at [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/) as a solution to your needs.  People have already gone to the effort of making it perform well, and if it does need to be improved, then when you improve it everyone in the community will benefit.

Next, the indentation in your code listing is unfortunately messed up, making it hard to really see what your code is doing.  Hopefully the following makes sense, but you should try to correct the code listing so it accurately reflects what you're doing, and make sure to double check code listings in future questions.

As far as what your code is doing that is preventing it from being fast, here are some ideas.

There's no limit to the number of outstanding HTTP requests in the program.  Without knowing what HTML you're actually parsing, I don't know if this is actually a problem, but if you end up issuing more than 20 or 30 HTTP requests at a time, it's very likely that you'll overload your network.  With TCP, this often means that connection setup will not succeed (certain setup packets get lost and there is a limit on how many times they will be retried).  Since you mentioned a lot of connection timeout errors, I suspect this is happening.

Consider how many HTTP requests the threaded version of your program will issue at a time.  Does the Twisted version potentially issue more?  If so, try imposing a limit on this.  Something like `twisted.internet.defer.DeferredSemaphore` might be an easy way to impose this limit (although it's far from the **best** way, so if it helps then you might want to start looking at better ways to impose this limit - but if the limit doesn't help then no point investing a lot of effort in a nicer limiting mechanism).

Next, by limiting the reactor threadpool to a maximum of 2 threads, you're severely hampering your ability to resolve names.  By default, name resolution (ie, DNS) is done using the reactor thread pool.  You have a couple options here.  I'm assuming there's a good reason you want to limit parsing to two concurrent threads.

First, you could leave the reactor threadpool alone and create your own thread pool for parsing.  See `twisted.python.threads.ThreadPool`.  You can set the maximum on this other thread pool to 2 to get the parsing behavior you want and the reactor is free to use as many threads as it wants for name resolution.

Second, you could continue to lower the reactor thread pool size and also configure the reactor to not use threads for name resolution.  `twisted.names.client.createResolver` will give you a name resolver which does just that, and `reactor.installResolver` lets you tell the reactor to use it instead of its default.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Paul for your response.  I am aware of scrapy, but wanted to use this scrapping project as a way to learn twisted as well as to compare with other techniques.  I am little confused by what you are referring to with the identation.  Can you give an example?  Since python uses identation as a way to define "blocks" of code instead of brackets like in C, I'm not sure how to go about what you are suggesting.  With respect to overloading the network, I don't think that is the case, at least in any obvious manner.

Comment: Also, I know the connection can handle more than the number of requests I am giving as I am successful at running several hundred requests at a time through hundreds of threads with my traditional threaded scrapper.  It is interesting that the main reactor loop is threaded itself (?).  I always thought it was a single thread and that by calling 'reactor.suggestThreadPool()' i was modifying the amount of threads outside of the reactor loop, or is it that twisted itself generates additional threads outside of the reactor loop to serve DNS requests, therefore making the "reactor thread pool"?

Comment: By using the reactor.callInThread() i was intending to make a thread outside of the main reactor loop thread, while with reactor.callFromThread(), I was hoping to insert my code execution back into the main reactor loop/thread.  Is that a correct understanding? I did try extending the suggestThreadPool to ~30 without any success : /.  Was hoping there was some obvious thing I was doing wrong here, but it sounds like my code is too convoluted to understand briefly.  I will try to make a simplied version of it while leaving the main twisted calls intact.  Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: For indentation, the code in your listing is not legal Python because it uses indentation incorrectly.  I expect this is an issue with stackoverflow markup and how you copy/pasted the code into your browser.  For example, the 1st and 2nd code lines of the `parsePage` function have the same level of indentation, even though the 1st line is a function definition and requires the following line to have greater indentation.